# У меня мини-програма предназначена для считания произведения елементов числа

Tags: python, функции

Например задаем число `25` и результат: `2*5=10`, но функция `rap()` почему-то выводит только последний элемент в случае `25` в списке `fold` оставляет только `5` и если напишем например `12334334`, функция оставит только  `4`.

```
firstfold = []
def rap(a):
    while a > 0:
      fold.append(a % 10)
      a = a // 10
      return fold
a = int(input("Enter numbers: "))
rap(a)
firstfold.extend(fold)
print(firstfold)
result = 1  # перемножаем элементы между собой
for i in range(0, len(firstfold)):
   result = result * firstfold[i]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def rap(a):
    while a > 0:
      fold.append(a % 10)
      a = a // 10
      return fold
a = int(input("Enter numbers: "))
rap(a)
    firstfold.extend(fold)
    print(firstfold)
    result = 1 #перемножає елемнти між собою
    for i in range(0, len(firstfold)):
        result = result * firstfold[i]
    print(result)
```

Тут мы видим, что в функции `rap` возвращается некоторая глобальная переменная `fold` в конце первой итерации цикла. То есть `fold+(a%10, )`. Достаточно опустить инструкцию return на уровень ниже и объявить fold как локальную переменную перед циклом во избежание каких-либо ошибок при многократном вызове. Таким образом, в `fold` добавятся все цифры числа `a`.

```
def rap(a):
    fold=list()
    while a > 0:
        fold.append(a % 10)
        a = a // 10
    return fold
```

Comment: не знаю почему, но теперь у меня список пустой

Comment: Продолжайте учить язык. Если вы изменили только функцию `rap` на приведенную мной, то в вашем коде вы ее вызываете, а она возвращает этот самый список `fold`. Сделайте, к примеру, присвоение `fold=rap(a)`, иначе результат выполнения функции просто улетит в никуда.

Answer (score 1):

Слишком много кода.

```
from functools import reduce

reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, (int(c) for c in input()))
```

*ty to Shamus

Comment: Нужно перемножить. `functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, (int(c) for c in input("Number: ")))`